# Unpivot format for a table

Tags: sql

I have a table with format-

```
Name | Value A | Value B | Comment
ABC       100      50        Test1
DEF       200      60        Test2
```

I want the result in the format

```
Name |   AorB   | Values  | Comment
ABC     Value A     100      Test1
ABC     Value B     50       Test1
DEF     Value A     200      Test2
DEF      ValueB     60       Test2
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to achieve that:

```
select Name, 'Value A' as AorB, valueA as [Values], Comment
from Table1 t1

union

select Name, 'Value B' as AorB, valueB as [Values], Comment
from Table1 t1
```

Working sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70f05/2

Comment: Oops..but today I rechecked and found that the values are not coming in the new generated columns!!I am getting null in valueA,valueB and Comment columns :(

Comment: @Richa is the data source OK?